# State of ColumList in SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5

I have a SAPUI5 m.columnlist contained inside m.table. I am supposed to click on any one of the item of columnlist which takes you to new page. From new page when you navigate back to the old page, the list scrolls to the top. I wished to maintain its state from where it is clicked and that item to be selected which was selected previously.

Getting no idea ho to go ahead with this.